# How to filter DiscrimnatorMaps with Api Platform?

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

Using Api Platform 2.6, and SF 4.4, I would like to use an Entity as a Discriminator and filter it.

I have 3 Entities: `Resource`, `Collaborator` and `Material`

Resource is the super mapped class, and defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={
 *     "company": "exact",
 *     "collaborator.lastname":"partial",
 *     "lastname": "partial",
 *     "title": "partial",
 *     "material.title":"partial"
 * })
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"resource"="Resource", "collaborator"="Collaborator", "material"="Material"})
 */
class Resource
{
```

I want to allow to filter all resources (`Collaborator` and `Material`) by some of their properties (for example **title** belongs to `Material`, and **lastname** belongs to `Collaborator`).

For now, these filters don't appear in the Api Doc, is it possible at least ? I can't find many informations on Git / Doc.

Comment: Not sure about the response, but did you try to create an api platform resource on each entity instead of the main one ?

Comment: Would https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1462#issuecomment-814218171 help ?

Comment: I have both, but I would like a single endpoint to search in both sub entites